# Shared angular 2 module throwing error while building aot

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I have created a shared angular 2 module for separating the reusable components. Everything works fine but getting the below error while building aot, pfb the error

```
Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol Injectable in D:/Shared_Module/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/metadata.d.ts, resolving symbol OpaqueToken in D:/ Shared_ Module/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_token.d.ts, resolving symbol OpaqueToken in D:/Shared_ Module/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_token.d.ts
```

PFB sample code and code structure

```
Base_Module
------------------
|
|___module.ts @NgModule
|
|___components
|
|___node_modules
|
|___package.json
|
|___tsconfig.json

Shared_Module
------------------
|
|___module.ts @NgModule
|
|___components -> Shared_Components
|
|___node_modules
|
|___package.json
|
|___tsconfig.json
```

**Below is the module.ts from Base module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Shared_Module } from './../../../../SharedModule/module'; --**Including the shared module here**

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedModule  -- **New shared module**
  ],
  exports:   [],
  bootstrap: []
})

export class Base_Module { }
```

**Below is the module.ts from shared module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  exports:   [Shared_Component],
  bootstrap: []
})

export class Shared_Module { }
```

Here is the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },

  "files": [
    "src/app/module.ts",
    "src/main.ts"
  ],

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "genDir": "aot",
   "skipMetadataEmit" : true
}
}
```

App is working fine. What could be wrong with aot compilation. All helps are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, should import `CommonModule`, not `BrowserModule` (in shared module).

See here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-browser-vs-common-module

Second, `OpaqueToken` is deprecated:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html

Use `InjectionToken` instead:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/InjectionToken-class.html

See if these things help.

Comment: putting CommonModule instead of BrowserModule didn't work

Comment: yeah, that wasn't going to fix your problem, it's just best practice for a high performing app, per the link.

Comment: @chrispy
I am getting the same error but couldn't able to find out where and in which file the exact problem is. You said "OpaqueToken is deprecated" but where do I find OpaqueToken in code?

Comment: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol Injectable in /home/user/node/multi-store/node_modules/ep-shared/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol ɵf in /home/user/node/multi-store/node_modules/ep-shared/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol ɵf in /home/user/node/multi-store/node_modules/ep-shared/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.t